# jquery datatable loaded via ajax is not registered as a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am loading some HTML via jquery ajax, and as part of that response there is a script reference to jquery Datatables. I see the script loading fine, but the plugin is not registered with jQuery (which was part of tte initial page load). So, when I call $(container).DataTable(...) it says the function is undefined. The same code works when datatable is loaded normally, not via ajax. For some reason, loading it dynamically causes this failure. Any pointers to what might be causing it?

Comment: It should be fine, unless the AJAX call actually removes the script originally loaded. Could that be it?

Comment: no, I don't think that's it. the jQuery reference still resolves just fine ie. jQuery and $ are both defined. But like I mentioned above, even though jQuery is defined, dataTables doesn't register itself and continues being undefined.

Comment: you can try using the **getScript** from jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `<script>` tags are not executed when content is injected into the page, see [Element.innerHTML - Security considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations).

The simplest approach would be to include DataTables CSS/JS files in your main page and remove it from your AJAX content. I have excluded jQuery since you've mentioned that it's part of your main page already.

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css">  

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Another option would be to load DataTables dynamically, as shown below. However you would need to use some page identification mechanism to determine by page ID whether it requires DataTables library. Besides the script below would be more complex if you require other libraries in addition to DataTables.

```
$.ajax("/path/to/script.php")
    .done(function(){
        $('head').append(
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />')
                .attr('href', '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/css/jquery.dataTables.css') 
        );

        $.ajax(
            url: '//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js', 
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'script'
        ).done(function(){
           // DataTables initialization
        });
    });
```